# How to check if secondary database definition exists

Tags: database, 9

Can anyone please help me on how to check if secondary database is set. If not throw an error.

I am currently defining database connection as below.

```
Database::getConnection('default', 'sqlite')
```

I am trying to defining a if , else condition based the database defining.

When I try

```
if(Database::getConnection('default', 'sqlite')){
  echo success;
}else {
  echo fail;
}
```

I am getting below error. If secondary database definition is not defined in settings.php

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: 
The specified database connection is not defined: sqlite in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 811 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a connection has been defined, I would use code similar to the following one.

```php
if ($connections = Database::getAllConnectionInfo() && isset($connections['default']['sqlite'])) {
  // The connection is defined.
}
```

[`Database::getConnection()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Database.php/function/Database%3A%3AgetConnection/9.3.x) returns a connection object, and it could return the one for default/primary server, when the requested information is for an ignored connection or the requested connection isn't defined.

```php
  // If the requested target does not exist, or if it is ignored, we fall back
  // to the default target. The target is typically either "default" or
  // "replica", indicating to use a replica SQL server if one is available. If
  // it's not available, then the default/primary server is the correct server
  // to use.
  if (!empty(self::$ignoreTargets[$key][$target]) || !isset(self::$databaseInfo[$key][$target])) {
    $target = 'default';
  }
  if (!isset(self::$connections[$key][$target])) {

    // If necessary, a new connection is opened.
    self::$connections[$key][$target] = self::openConnection($key, $target);
  }
```

This means that expecting an exception from `Database::getConnection()` when the connection isn't defined is wrong.

Comment: Thanks its better than the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

```php
try {
    $connection = Database::getConnection('default', 'sqlite');
}
catch (Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException $e) {
    // Do something here.
}
finally {
    // Optional: do something in any case.
}
```

Comment: Thanks , it works. But just wondering whether we have any method in core to check if the connection exists. Something like `hasConnection()`

Answer (score -1):

Although [cilefen](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/17684/cilefen) pointed me in the right direction. It still throws fatal error when using cilefen's answer. I am able to resolve this issue by slightly modifying exception handling.

```
try {
  $connection = Database::getConnection('default', 'sqlite');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  return new \Exception("SQLite Database configurtion is not setup.", 1);
}
```

Created a core issue [#3282024](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3282024) to add native method to check database connection.

Comment: You may need a slash before the exception, like \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException. \Exception could be anything at all.

Comment: Adding slash produces the same error.